# All dynos are stopped as soon as one finished with heroku local

Tags: heroku, heroku-cli

I have a very simple FLASK webserver that I run in the web dyno of the heroku platform. I also have a very simple python program that runs on a separate dyno, which prints "hello world" and then exits.

My procfile looks like this

```
web: gunicorn --bind 0.0.0.0:$PORT wsgi
test: python helloWorld.py
```

With heroku local, as soon as the hello world program finishes, the web dyno gets killed too:

```
$ heroku local

8:54:29 AM test.1 |  Hello World
[DONE] Killing all processes with signal  SIGINT
8:54:29 AM test.1 Exited Successfully
8:54:29 AM web.1  |  Traceback (most recent call last):
8:54:29 AM web.1  |    File "/anaconda3/bin/gunicorn", line 7, in <module>
8:54:29 AM web.1  |      from gunicorn.app.wsgiapp import run
8:54:29 AM web.1  |    File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 9, in <module>
8:54:29 AM web.1  |      from gunicorn.app.base import Application
8:54:29 AM web.1  |    File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gunicorn/app/base.py", line 11, in <module>
8:54:29 AM web.1  |      from gunicorn._compat import execfile_
8:54:29 AM web.1  |    File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gunicorn/_compat.py", line 267, in <module>
8:54:29 AM web.1  |      import inspect
8:54:29 AM web.1  |    File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/inspect.py", line 1087, in <module>
8:54:29 AM web.1  |      'args, varargs, varkw, defaults, kwonlyargs, kwonlydefaults, annotations')
8:54:29 AM web.1  |    File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/collections/__init__.py", line 397, in namedtuple
8:54:29 AM web.1  |      exec(s, namespace)
8:54:29 AM web.1  |    File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
8:54:29 AM web.1  |  KeyboardInterrupt
8:54:29 AM web.1  Exited with exit code null
```

How can I prevent this?

I know that the problem is with helloWorld.py exiting. If I create a script that doesn't terminate, the problem doesn't occur.

```
print("Hello World", flush=True)
while True:
    pass
```

Answer (score 0):

Apparently this is deliberate behavior from foreman. See the discussion on [Github](https://github.com/ddollar/foreman/issues/687):

> Foreman assumes all the processes are long-lived. If any of the processes exits, Foreman stops all processes.

The only solution would be to make HelloWorld.py long lived.